# TFS restore from TFS 2013 DB backup taken manually

Tags: tfs

I have only all TFS DB backup which was taken manually before server crashed, I want to restore the TFS instance from the same backup. Can anybody help me on the approach, process or link how to do it. It will be great help for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Restore data to the same location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-same-location)

Answer (score -1):

This can be a good starting point: [Back up and restore TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/back-up-restore-tfs) from MS site.
No fear!